# Is there a rule about double negations that aren't meant as double negations (e.g. "We don't need no education")?

Tags: double-negation

How can you explain that this double negation is not a double negation? Is there a rule in English about this kind of sentence?

*PS / Do I have to mention Pink Floyd Copyright ? :-)*

Edit : Since there are a lot of Pink Floyd related explanation, I'll bring a Freddy Mercury one : "*I don't have time for no monkey business*", which I also understand as "I don't have time for monkey business". Am I right ?

Comment: I don't know nothing about this.

Comment: But if ya don't get no education, ya ain't gonna get no good job.

Comment: Ironical grammatical error due to having no education?

Comment: @Brian yeah right...

Comment: @Tester101: Perhaps it was actually due to having enough education to know that English teachers are not always right about such things. For example, [split infinitives](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2117/are-split-infinitives-grammatically-incorrect-or-are-they-valid-constructs)...

Comment: +1 We don't need no thought control.

Comment: @SamB: One of the reasons he's rebelling against the education system.  No pudding for you ;p

Comment: @Tester101: the proper term for it is the *school* system; education is something rather different from schooling ;-P

Comment: No, you wouldn't need to mention a copyright because copyright cannot apply to short phrases or single sentences.

Comment: @SamB: looks like no pudding for me either.

Comment: On a related note, I'm surprised no one has brought up George Orwell yet: "A not unblack dog was chasing a not unsmall rabbit across a not ungreen field."

Comment: She is not unattractive...

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Doubled negatives are often used casually in certain dialects to indicate *negative concord*, an intensification of negation rather than an inversion of it. This typically happens when both words involved are simple negatives, and is most common with *no* standing in for *a*, *an*, or *any* alongside *don't* or *ain't*.

So you can safely assume that

> He isn't *not* going to the concert.

is double negation proper, because it has emphasis, as is

> She wasn't unimpressed.

because this is [litotes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litotes), whereas

> I ain't no hillbilly.

is negative concord, because it's obviously casual, and uses *ain't no* in place of *am no* or *am not a*. (It's also a patent lie, but that's beside the point.)

Comment: +1 for fancy words I did not know until now

Comment: Tangent: in some languages, "double negative" is the correct way. For example, in French, "ne me mange pas" ("don't eat me") - "ne" and "pas" are both there for negation. In Spanish, this can be done for emphasis: "Nunca jamas te comeria" ("I would never ever eat you") - "nunca" and "jamas" are both essentially "never."

Comment: @Nathan Long: Well...kind of. In French, *ne* never stands alone, so it's really just there to introduce negative constructions, and some constructions with *ne* aren't even negative, such as *ne...que*, meaning *only* as in *je ne mange que pamplemousse*, "I only eat grapefruit".

Comment: @Jon: A structurally closer translation would be "I eat nothing but grapefruit". In "ne pas", it was "ne" that was the negation, while "pas" was a mere intensifier, like "at all" or "shit" or "ever". This comes from sentences of the type "je ne marche pas" (I do not walk a step), from which the intensifier eventually came to felt as an essential part of the negation. Cf. "point" and "personne". Note that English and most other Germanic languages also went through a double-negative phase in the Middle Ages.

Comment: @Cerberus: You're right, but I guess what I was really getting at is that in *modern* French the *ne* is just a vestige of the old Gallic (cf. Irish *ní).* In casual speech, *ne* is quite frequently omitted, basically wherever it's unambiguous. And of course negative concord makes a lot more sense in a heavily inflected language such as English was for most of the Middle Ages.

Comment: @Jon: Oh, I knew there were some traces of Celtic origin, but I didn't know they included such a prominent word as "ne"—I was told it came from Latin? Or didn't you mean Celtic by "old Gallic"? It is indeed funny that "ne" might be on its way to oblivion in French: I wonder whether English will return to regular double negation. "Not" has already been weakened, as it is often "n't". I wonder whether there is any relation to its now preferred place after the finite verb.

Comment: @Cerberus: Right, I was referring to French's Celtic roots. I don't know enough to say how exactly the *nV* prefix came about in all these languages, other than a Proto-Indo-European (and perhaps general human) propensity for using nasals for negation. If there's one thing I wish English would drop, it's the vestigial *do;* Frisian, for instance, expresses negatives and questions just fine with simple inversion.

Comment: @Jon: Are there non-IE languages that use nasal forms of negation? That would be interesting. Chomsky would like it. English *do*-support is indeed a bit cumbersome, it might well be got rid of. P.S. Frisian and Dutch use inversion with questions, not with negations—we don't need any marker apart from the negation itself (yet...).

Comment: @Cerberus: I don't know enough to guess if it's all that common outside of the Indo-European family, but Japanese for instance has *-masen* as the negative of *-masu* for verbs, as well as *-nai*. Although, now I don't want it to be true because I don't like Chomsky. Also, I didn't mean to imply that inversion is or ought to be used for negation, just that I'd prefer we always use, say, "I go not" over "I don't go". The former is *allowed* but no longer common. Heck, it'd be even nicer if English were purely analytic, but *that's* just a pipe dream.

Answer (score 19):

It’s worth noting that this “inverts” the sense only in *Standard Written English*. In [AAVE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_American_Vernacular_English) and other vernaculars this is not only grammatically correct, it’s also **semantically correct**, i.e. the normal negation is in some contexts always created via double negation which does *not* resolve to a positive.

The same is true for many other languages: if you’re not convinced that a vernacular is a valid grammatical description (but from a linguistic point of view, it is!), take French, where double negative is *mandatory* (most of the time) by prescribed grammar rules: to negate a verb, it is embedded into “ne … pas” (or archaically “ne … point”) which are affix and suffix and both indicate negation, even when used in isolation (which does happen occasionally).

(Since this has garnered so many upvotes, let me give credit where credit is due, and also a reading suggestion: This information is from Steven Pinker’s excellent book [*The Language Instinct*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0061336467).)

Comment: Upvoted this, since [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/207557/in-the-rap-baby-got-back-does-sir-mix-a-lots-anaconda-want-buns-or-not) got duped here, and it was a question about AAVE. We should point out that Rap, Blues, and much Rock&Roll music typically have their lyrics written in AAVE, so this comes up a lot in popular culture.

Answer (score 4):

He made this "mistake" of double negation on purpose. It is a form of protest in itself; what he meant was: *we don't need education, we will speak (or do) as we want*. He was going against the "imposed" correctness and etiquette.

Comment: Well, there's another line that seems to support your interpretation: "Teachers, leave them kids alone". Which, from a prescriptive point of view, is ungrammatical too.

Comment: @JuanPabloCalifano: I never actually noticed that! Nice!

Answer (score 2):

When a sentence with two negative elements is interpreted as only being negated once, we call this negative concord (also popularly known as double negatives). This phenomenon is widespread in informal speech throughout varieties of English worldwide, including Appalachian English and African American English. However, there are also differences between the types of negative concords allowed by different varieties of English. Negative concord is also common in many other languages, such as Spanish, Italian, and Portuguese.

Negative concord can be present in multiple configurations in English. One type of negative concord is when a negative word, such as no, nobody, or never, occurs after a negated auxiliary (also known as a helping verb, a word such as do or have that adds grammatical meaning such as tense or aspect to a main verb) or modal (a word such as might or could that indicates necessity or possibility of the main verb it occurs with). An example would the the sentence in the question above, “I don’t have time for no monkey business”. It is also possible to have negative words in the subject position co-occurring with sentential negation, as in, “Nobody couldn’t handle him”.

For more information, see the discussion of this phenomenon on the Yale Grammatical Diversity Project website, in particular our page on Negative Concord: https://ygdp.yale.edu/phenomena/negative-concord.

Answer (score 1):

What is correct may not be easy to understand, and what is easy to understand may not be correct. To a limit.

On reflection, it seems common that only no and ain't can be used to intensify a negation rather than a double negation, whereas correct English requires using any, isn't, or aren't.

I would probably never hear "This paper ain't unacceptable," but it's conceivable to hear "This paper ain't gonna get no acceptation from me."

Also, "This paper ain't unacceptable" is ambiguous, so I would expect to hear "This paper ain't unacceptable, but you gotta be proofreadin' some mo'."

Perhaps you can use exercises like asking what a certain written sentence might mean:

1. You're not wrong.
2. You ain't wrong. (still double negation)
3. I ain't gonna take any shit from you. (possibly ambiguous, a sign of someone trying to copy a dialect, but slipping up with "any")
4. I'ma takin' no crap from you.
5. I'ma takin' no attitude from none of youse.
6. None of you ain't right. (ambiguous)
7. None of you ain't wrong. (ambiguous triple negation)
8. Not one of you isn't wrong. (crystal clear triple negation)

The comprehension of an ambiguous phrase often depends on the context in which it appears.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the use in Another Brick in the Wall, just as important as the irony it's also how a child of that class, era and region would probably express that they didn't think they needed educating.

While some hear a double negative as incorrect, some hear it as emphasis.

Answer (score 0):

It's a double negation, but it's unintentional (or rather supposed to sound unintentional), so the meaning is still a single negation. The sentence is grammatically correct, but incorrect in the sense that the actual meaning is not what was intended.

The strict meaning of the sentence is the double negation, but as it's obviously a mistake you interpret the intention of the sentence instead, which is the single negation. The obvious difference between the actual meaning and the intended meaning is used here to demonstrate a lack of education.

Comment: On the contrary, there is no reason to suppose it is unintentional. And despite what generations of pedagogues and pedants have claimed, the sentence means exactly what it intended to mean, unless you apply a perverse set of semantic rules which belong to logic, not to human language. Pinker shows in "The Language Instinct" that you *can* construct instances where a double negative really does cancel out ("Try as I might, I cannot get *no* satifaction from this") but no English speaker actually misunderstands "I can't get no satisfaction", therefore it means what it is supposed to.

Comment: So you are saying that it's correct only because it can be understood? By that reason you could do practically any thing to the languige as long ass its still posible too under stand itt, and its stil nott incorect?

Comment: No, he's saying that it's correct because it is not occurring in a context where the rules of logic take precedence over those of the vernacular, such as a treatise on mathematics, [`##c`](http://twkm.freeshell.org/c.html), a Q&A site about programming, or (counter-intuitive though it may seem) Alice in Wonderland. (That isn't the only factor, of course -- Konrad's wonderful answer explains how you can get an actual, *canceling*, double negation even outside that sort of context -- but it is the main one.)

Comment: The rule against double negation is an artificial one, like the rule against splitting infinitives -- they can all be traced to Seventeenth- and Eighteenth-century prescriptivists who wanted to make English fit the grammar of Latin and Greek neatly. Shakespeare is peppered with double negatives, and not in the mouths of fools and peasants, neither, and if you stripped them from Chaucer you'd have little left to tell on the way to Canterbury.

Answer (score 0):

This is an ironic phrase because the the sentence is not conventionally grammatically correct.  However, it follows a speach pattern of groups of people in the US often socially and economically marginalized.  These people do not like being looked down upon and phrases like this are often said with a level of defiance.

My grandfather used to say, "I don't need no ej-a-mication". He intentionally mispronounced the word to mock it.  But really, he dropped out of school around the eighth grade and was poor most of his life, so he might have been a liitle ashamed of his situation and was using the phrase to deflect pity.

Answer (score -2):

You could assume that commas have been left out:

```
"We do, not need, no education"
```

in which case the implication would me that although education is needed, they do not 'do' it (incorrect, but could be appropriate as slang).

Alternatively:

```
"We do not [have], need no, education"
```

Where the repition is used as emphasis: `"we do not [have] education, and we need no education"`

Both of these are a bit of a stretch, and while possible, I doubt they are what Pink Floyd intended.

Comment: Why the downvotes?