# Is "Either of the two" used correctly?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, grammaticality

"She would cry at the thought of it, sometimes scream about it, either of the two bore no fruit."

I know we can use, "neither of the two helped" but I wanted a different style.

Comment: See [Why is it “either . . . or” and “neither . . . nor”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18340/why-is-it-either-or-and-neither-nor) Note that ***neither*** is a "negative polarity" usage, and *that's* what you need in your "negating" context (***neither** of them bore **any** fruit*, not ***...no** fruit*).

Comment: The use of *either* is fine, but not in the way it's currently used. It should really be *…, with no fruit borne from either (of the two).* In other words, the phrase, essentially, needs to be reversed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not incorrect, but redundant. Either means one or the other so it would be more polished, but still somewhat stilted, saying:

> either bore no fruit.

Or if you want it more succinctly, using neither:

> neither bore fruit.

But in keeping with the flow of your sentence, much rather:

> neither of which bore fruit.