# Difference between "you can't do nothing" and "you can't do anything"

Tags: differences

I have heard people say for example:

> You can't do nothing to me

is it the same thing as

> you can't do anything to me

If no, what's the difference?

I personally think the latter is correct. Would love to hear you guys thought on this.

Comment: Related question, [Meaning of “you don't need no memory” and its grammar or rhetoric](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20871/meaning-of-you-dont-need-no-memory-and-its-grammar-or-rhetoric).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In proper English, the latter is correct; the former (a double negative) is sometimes used as an affectation of dialect or slang and means the same thing.

Comment: The former, a so-called double negative, is perfectly normal and grammatical in many varieties of English around the world; but not, as far as I know, any varieties which are called "standard".