# Are double negatives *always* wrong?

Tags: double-negation

Could you use these two sentences the same way?
Which one is worse:

> This wasn't no common day.
>
> This wasn't a common day.

Comment: Related question, [Is there a rule about double negations that aren't meant as double negations (e.g. “We don't need no education”)?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8777/is-there-a-rule-about-double-negations-that-arent-meant-as-double-negations-e).

Comment: In Standard Englishes, a double negative is never not wrong when negative polarity is intended. But it ain't no lie to say it's perfectly acceptable in some dialects, at least conversationally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double negatives are used to convey uncertainty:

> "His actions were **not ir**responsible."

The writer is not condemning the actions as irresponsible, but he is unsure as to whether the actions were responsible.

Double negatives are also used to water-down the strength of a statement:

> "Double negatives are **not un**grammatical." (as opposed to "Double negatives are grammatical.")

The writer wants the reader to use double negatives cautiously.

Comment: So "This wasn't no common day?", means the speaker is pondering about the potentiality of this day.

Comment: @zehelvion In conversation, the speaker could just be saying the day wasn't a common day.  The speaker may just have a habit of using double negatives.

Comment: Yes. If the speaker is presenting a question?

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much.

> This wasn't an ordinary day.
>
> This was no ordinary day.

These are correct. Your first example is wrong.

Comment: So it's like irregardless, the double negative sound like one negative because of the pronunciation?

Comment: In careful or formal speech.  Many dialects use double negatives frequently, with no confusion about meaning, and consistency of form.  But it is not considered "standard English," and should be used in formal contexts or when you want to make a good impression (assuming that the people you want to impress don't talk like that themselves.)