# "Try not to" vs "try to not"

Tags: grammar, verbs, infinitives

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Order of “not” with infinitive](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23152/order-of-not-with-infinitive)

When negating [verbs that are commonly followed by the infinitive](http://www.englishpage.com/gerunds/infinitive_list.htm), is there a difference in meaning between placing the "not" before and after the "to"?

e.g.

> I try not to care

or

> I try to not care