# Is there a difference in meaning between "does not seem to" and "seems not to"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, verbs, word-order, negation

Consider the following sentences:

> 1. Try not to be alarmed if a rule doesn’t seem to work for a specific sentence.
> 2. Try not to be alarmed if a rule seems not to work for a specific sentence.

Is there a difference in meaning between "does not seem to work" and "seems not to work"?

Comment: Related: [Order of “not” with infinitive](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23152/order-of-not-with-infinitive), which covers another choice, "to not work" vs. "not to work".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, there is no difference.

*[Seem](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/97613/15299)* is a verb that governs [infinitive complements](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/complements.pdf) and allows [Negative-Raising](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/negative-raising). That means that negation in the infinitive complement of *seem*, or *want*, or other Neg-Raising verbs, as in

- *The rule seems **not to work***.               [ = *... **to not work***]
- *He wants me **not to go** tomorrow.*  [ = *... **to not go** tomorrow.*]

can also appear, instead, in the matrix clause with *seem* or *want*

- *The rule **doesn't seem** to work*.
- *He **doesn't want** me to go tomorrow.*

**without** a change in meaning.

This is not true of most predicates, which don't allow Neg-Raising. *(Be) Easy*, for instance, is a more normal predicate; the two sentences below do **not** mean the same thing.

- *It's easy for him **not to smile***.
- *It's **not easy** for him to smile.*

> **Edit**: Pursuant to RegDwight's comment above on split infinitives, I should mention that **both** the unsplit variant ***not*** to smile **and** the split variant *to **not** smile* are in the complement clause, i.e, not Neg-Raised -- though they are likewise equivalent in grammaticality and meaning. Either form can be regarded as the "source" of the Neg-Raised ***not*** easy to smile

Comment: I suspect it's not a common practice, but I almost always use these two phrases to distinguish between different knowledge claims, and it comes up in my writing all the time. If something "does not seem to X," it fails to present evidence of X. And if a thing "seems not to X," it presents evidence that it _doesn't_ X. That is, the latter indicates presence of confirmation, and the former indicates absence of disconfirmation. In both cases, "seems" signals that the observation is not sufficient to settle the matter of whether thing does X.

Comment: @Tom Such distinctions can be made, and if one is careful in making them, one can train one's readers to recognize them. But the contrast is very pointillistic, and most people wouldn't notice it unless you styled the text around it, as you describe.

Comment: Are you saying I can't take my pet distinction "on holiday"? ;)

Comment: Check and see first what the local leash laws are.

Answer (score 2):

There is a slight difference.

Clearly both sentence do not say that "the rule doesn't work". They talk about a preliminary examination and your conclusion so far, which may turn out incorrect in the future.

"It doesn't seem to work" is a slightly weaker statement. The speaker hasn't put much effort into the examination so far. He or she hasn't seen evidence that it works yet, but hasn't looked much at the problem. "It seems not to work" is a strong statement. The speaker believes that it doesn't work, but accepts the possibility to be wrong. That said, there isn't *much* difference.