# having no vs not having

Tags: negative-raising

> Having no friends or not having friends.

Are they equal or different?
 I think they are in same format with these two sentences being equal. Do you not like him? or Don't you like him?

Comment: They are equal. Negatives can negate the verb phrase (_not [have friends]_) or the direct object (_have no friends_). In both cases, the whole sentence is negative. If you have nothing, you don't have anything.

Comment: Related and probable duplicates: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/140052 http://english.stackexchange.com/a/66274

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, John Lawler wrote:

> They are equal. Negatives can negate the verb phrase (*not [have friends]*) or the direct object (*have no friends*). In both cases, the whole sentence is negative. If you have nothing, you don't have anything.

But please check out his elaborate answers in the linked-to duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words, but the phenomena discussed in the links are not what's at issue; Neg-Raising is not involved here because these are both simple sentences and Neg-Raising is cyclic and therefore applies only to subordinate clauses. This is just the difference between negating the focus or negating a constituent that contains the focus, like [_only_ and _even_](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/115157/15299).