# How to say the interrogative form with a base form of a verb ..in English?

Tags: negation, infinitives

In French language, I will say

"*Comment ne pas être repéré*".

But I want to translate it into English.

Do we say "How to not be spotted" or "How not to be spotted"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Order of "not" with infinitive](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23152/order-of-not-with-infinitive) //  [Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=how+not+to+be%2Chow+to+not+be&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chow%20not%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chow%20to%20not%20be%3B%2Cc0) would indicate that 'How not to be ... ' is used more often than 'How to not be ...', but both are used.

Comment: Learn: "How to Not be Caught in a Nutritional Conundrum" [here](http://aroundthetableri.blogspot.com/2012/01/nutrition-mistakes-learn-how-to-not-be.html) (contains recipes), and "How not to be caught by PayPal phishing scams" [here](https://totalityservices.co.uk/how-not-to-be-caught-by-paypal-phishing-scams/)