# Grammaticality of Star Trek's slogan

Tags: grammar, split

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are split infinitives grammatically incorrect, or are they valid constructs?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2117/are-split-infinitives-grammatically-incorrect-or-are-they-valid-constructs)

Star Trek's slogan:

> To boldly go where no man has gone before.

"To boldy go" sounds right, but I was told by my friend that this is actually grammatically wrong because it is a split infinitive. I don't agree, because it seems to sound right. Is this a split infinitive, or something else?

Comment: Reg, I'm not asking whether split infinitives are right or not, I'm asking whether this is a split infinitive or not.

Comment: What is the definition of split infinitive? Does the above sentence fit that pattern? Anyway, whether obvious or not, it's still a question whether split infinitives are 'correct' or not, which is answered in the duplicate.

Comment: The second answer to that other question actually uses the Star Trek slogan as an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_infinitive) explains it all:

> A split infinitive is an English-language grammatical construction in which a word or phrase, usually an adverb or adverbial phrase, comes between the marker to and the bare infinitive (uninflected) form of a verb.
>
> A split infinitive occurs in the opening sequence of the Star Trek television series: to boldly go where no man has gone before. Here, the adverb "boldly" splits the full infinitive "to go". More rarely, the term compound split infinitive is used to describe situations in which the infinitive is split by more than one word: The population is expected to more than double in the next ten years.
>
> As the split infinitive became more common in the **19th** century, some grammatical authorities sought to introduce a **prescriptive rule against it**. The construction is still the subject of disagreement among native English speakers as to whether it is grammatically correct or good style: "No other grammatical issue has so divided English speakers since the split infinitive was declared to be a solecism in the 19c [19th century]: raise the subject of English usage in any conversation today and it is sure to be mentioned". However, most **modern English usage guides have dropped the objection** to the split infinitive.

Comment: And why should we believe anything Wikipedia says?