# "How best to handle" vs. "how to best handle"

Tags: grammaticality, adverbs, word-order, infinitives, adverb-position

Are there rules on the placement of 'best'?

> - They are deciding how to *best* handle the matter.
> - They are deciding how *best* to handle the matter.

Is one of them wrong?

Comment: Beware of the semantics of "how to best" (though not an issue in the given sentence).

Answer (score 6):

Both are grammatical, but the second is probably found more frequently.

Comment: Do they mean the same thing?

Comment: I would say so.

Comment: @planem the average speaker interprets them the same way, but they could have different meaning under strict rules.

Comment: @NewAlexandria: Okay, I'll bite. What are these "strict rules", and what different meanings might they distinguish between OP's two alternatives?

Comment: I'm sure you have plenty of rep to put a nice bounty on that question ;)

Answer (score 2):

Like Barrie England said, both are grammatically correct and mean the same. But it is considered non-standard to split infinitives (*to + verb* forms) by many. So by that account, saying *how to best handle* (infinitive is split as *best* is placed between *to* and *handle*) might sound unusual, though grammatically correct.

Comment: The myth of the split infinitive was demolished long ago.

Comment: +1 A good valid point all the same. That's how we spell *Inglish Teeture* then?

Comment: @Kris: That's just to remind myself constantly that English is a _non-phonetic language_. I always tell my students not to try to find logic in the way English words are spelt, something they often do and then find it hard to accept this lack of logic in spelling since their native languages are all _phonetic_. They just wish things could be spelt the way they are said :)

Answer (score 2):

They're both valid, and I can't even be bothered to address the ["split infinitive"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2117/are-split-infinitives-grammatically-incorrect-or-are-they-valid-constructs) (non-)issue, but [this](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=decide%20how%20best%20to,decide%20how%20to%20best&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=)

[image]

is all you need to know if you want to sound like a native speaker.

---

The reason some people *"decide **how to best** handle the matter"* is probably nothing to do with "split infinitives" (which really are a [complete non-issue](http://www.guardian.co.uk/notesandqueries/query/0,5753,-23994,00.html), here and in other contexts). It's just that they're bothered by the fact that the "standard" usage clashes somewhat with similar constructions where the position of the adverb radically affects the meaning...

> *Decide **how quickly to** handle the matter*.
>   *Decide **how to quickly** handle the matter*.

...are *not* the same! In the first version, *how* would normally be taken to modify *quickly* (i.e. - the decision is about *how quickly* the matter should be handled, not how to handle it *quickly*). But *how* certainly can't modify *best* in the same way (that would be deciding *how well* to handle things). And if you're thinking that *"quickly"* isn't the right word, note that...

> ["how quickest to"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22how%20quickest%20to%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) occurs 367 times in Google Books, whereas
>   ["how to quickest"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22how%20quickest%20to%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=d&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22how%20to%20quickest%22&oq=%22how%20to%20quickest%22&gs_l=serp.12...0.0.1.3039.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0...1c.tK0GamJmkbY&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.ZG4&fp=631c27e467ebe0f0&bpcl=40096503&biw=1412&bih=897) occurs only *once*.

Comment: -1 "how to best" = "how to get the better of" -- pitfall!

Comment: @Kris. Can you provide an example of two complete sentences that show the difference, in the way that FF's do for _quickly_?

Comment: @BarrieEngland "... the abbess taught her how to best an opponent who is larger and stronger ..." (books.google.com/books?isbn=0889204977) "How to best an opponent using 4 dimensional strategy." (http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDcQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.slideshare.net%2FSeriousGamesAssoc%2Fevolving-serious-games-beyond-training-by-phaedra-boinodiris-serious-play-conference-2012&ei=02zVUIPrE4fUrQfEroCgBA&usg=AFQjCNGjaoJjhBpwxI0Sb10vjcK7EUEfMw&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.bmk)

Comment: @BarrieEngland nGrams results need to be handled with circumspection.

Comment: @Kris. Thank you. I know how _best_ can be used as a verb. What I was looking for was a pair of sentences using _best_ modelled on FF’s _Decide how quickly to handle the matter_ and _Decide how to quickly handle the matter_.

Comment: @Kris: What Barrie said. It's grammatically impossible to interpret "best" as a verb in either of OP's constructions, so if that was your reason for downvoting I have to say you are mistaken.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @FumbleFingers 's Ngrams-based answer, some data from [COCA](http://corpus2.byu.edu/coca/) (450 million word corpus, (dwarfed by the Ngrams corpus, but higher quality data)). Consistent with what NGrams shows, Coca shows the non-split version to be roughly four times as frequent. This supports @Barrie England 's answer.

The search term `how best to [v*]` gives 775 hits. Top ten hits:

> 1        HOW BEST TO USE    38
>   2        HOW BEST TO ACHIEVE    30
>   3        HOW BEST TO DO 29
>   4        HOW BEST TO DEAL   28
>   5        HOW BEST TO MANAGE 24
>   6        HOW BEST TO PROTECT    24
>   7        HOW BEST TO HELP   20
>   8        HOW BEST TO HANDLE 18
>   9        HOW BEST TO APPROACH   17
>   10       HOW BEST TO RESPOND    17

The search term `how to best [v*]` gives 184 hits (roughty 1/4 as many). *handle* is 13th on the list with 3 hits. Top ten are:

> 1       HOW TO BEST USE    15
>   2        HOW TO BEST UTILIZE    7
>   3        HOW TO BEST PREPARE    6
>   4        HOW TO BEST MEET   6
>   5        HOW TO BEST EDUCATE    5
>   6        HOW TO BEST PROTECT    5
>   7        HOW TO BEST REACH  4
>   8        HOW TO BEST APPROACH   4
>   9        HOW TO BEST FACILITATE 4
>   10       HOW TO BEST MANAGE 4

Interestingly, when the search terms are as above, the non-split-infinitive version is more frequent. When I use @FumbleFingers 's query, `[decide] how best to [v*]` / `[decide] how to best [v*]`, the relative numbers are: 12 hits for the split infinitive, 56 hits for the non-split infinitive. The relative proportions remain more or less the same.

Comment: I don't understand the point of this answer. Your figures say the same as my chart, only not so clearly. Barrie says OP's second version *is probably found more frequently* - and we both agree "probably" is probably an understatement, to say the least. I don't see why you needed to produce all this "higher quality" data to prove what NGrams had already shown.

Comment: @FumbleFingers oops, I misread the NGrams graph. It shows the same as the COCA. anyways, this is just in the spirit of scholarly cooperation; it strengthens both of our answers to know that they are in agreement.

Comment: np. Have an upvote, since I see you've changed that *contrary to NGrams* bit. Anyway, it spurred me to consider *why* anyone would think there's an issue here in the first place. So I've thunk my thoughts, and extended my answer with them. Now we just have to wait for more votes to be cast by anyone else who agrees Barrie's answer is a bit *too* brief (we obviously do, or we wouldn't have bothered ourselves). I just want to see how many people will agree with StoneyB that both OP's versions are so contentious only a complete rewrite will do!

Answer (score 1):

SUPPLEMENTAL:
The answers by Barrie England and Inglish Teeture are entirely adequate. However, your two alternatives present a dilemma: would you rather annoy the readers who still hold to what Barrie calls the “myth of the split infinitive” or those readers who clamorously deny it?

Your job as a writer is to avoid annoying *anybody*, so your readers pay attention to what you’re saying rather than how you say it. Don’t give them anything to argue about. Sidestep the issue by **rewriting**:

> They are deciding how to handle the matter best.
>   They are deciding what the best way of handling the matter will be.

Or, simplest of all (and probably more accurate, too, since there’s no guarantee that the ‘best’ solution will be adopted):

> They are deciding how to handle the matter.

Comment: There's no substance whatsoever to this "split infinitive" business, as I'm sure you know. So why advise OP to take care not to offend the (fictitious) people who might believe in the myth?

Comment: @FumbleFingers  The "substance" is use (as you and jlovegren show), not belief. But three or four times a year I find people  actually *rewriting* my un-split infinitives because they've read articles decrying the "myth" and think they're *supposed to* split infinitives; so I've learned to avoid it.

Comment: Splitting hairs, but you still manage to ruffle feathers, with or without infinite rephrasing, as the comments show. I write what comes naturally and let the reader tear his hairs.

Comment: @StoneyB: Okay, I admit I was feeling a bit tetchy last night - I'm sure you have more experience than me when it comes to copy-editing and adverse criticism (justified or not). Me, I don't like the idea of pandering to pedantry in the first place, and the identification of split infinitives as "erroneous" doesn't really even have pedantry to back it up (it's more just out-and-out ignorance! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers  I agree with your characterization of "split infinitives", but what chaps my ass is being told by those less sophisticated than you that I *should* split the infinitive in circumstances where it's clearly less idiomatic.

Comment: I have great respect for [nohat](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/2122/2637), who is truly wise in the ways of words. Like you, he's good at putting his headline point right at the beginning, so there's no confusion about where he's coming from. In this specific case, *the only thing that should be avoided is awkwardness*. Sound advice, that.