# "Enables you to quickly and easily identify" vs. "enables you to identify quickly and easily"

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, adverbs, word-order, infinitives

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are split infinitives grammatically incorrect, or are they valid constructs?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2117/are-split-infinitives-grammatically-incorrect-or-are-they-valid-constructs)

I'm currently having a bit of a dispute and would appreciate your help please. Which one is more grammatically correct?

> - enables you to quickly and easily identify
> - enables you to identify quickly and easily

And why do you think the one that you've chosen?

Answer (score 4):

Both are equally grammatical, but also equally nonsensical because *identify* is missing its object. As soon as the object is added, the first alternative actually becomes preferable.

- > enables you to quickly and easily identify problems

  → perfectly natural
- > enables you to identify quickly and easily problems

  → weird, too much stuff between the verb and its object

(Whoever objects to the first order likely does so because of a made-up rule about "split infinitives", which has nothing to do with the reality of English grammar. See [this general question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2117/are-split-infinitives-grammatically-incorrect-or-are-they-valid-constructs) for details.)

Comment: How about "enables you to identify problems quickly and easily"? Sounds most natural to me.