# Is this sentence bugged? "adverb to verb"?

Tags: adverbs, sentence

> There lurks in most modern minds the notion that to desire our own
>   good and earnestly to hope for the enjoyment of it is a bad thing.

Is this "earnestly" an adverb? If it is, then why "earnestly to hope"? Shouldn't there be no "to" in between the adverb and the verb it modifies?

The original sentence is:

> If there lurks in most modern minds the notion that to desire our own
>   good and earnestly to hope for the enjoyment of it is a bad thing, I
>   submit that this notion has crept in from Kant and the Stoics and is
>   no part of the Christian faith.
>
> Lewis, C. S.. Weight of Glory (Collected Letters of C.S. Lewis) (p.
>   27). HarperCollins. Kindle Edition.

Comment: Where did you find the rule that says adverbs can't be used this way  with infinitives?

Comment: I earnestly hope I know where I found the rule, but I think I've never seen this kind of usage before. - or, should I say "I earnestly to hope..."?

Comment: Perhaps Mr Lewis did not wish to "split an infinitive."

Comment: The problem is that by placing the adverb before "to", it's not only outside the VP but outside the entire clause. Not acceptable.

Comment: Seems a duplicate of [Are split infinitives grammatically incorrect, or are they valid constructs?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2117/are-split-infinitives-grammatically-incorrect-or-are-they-valid-constructs)

Comment: @BillJ maybe your analysis is "not acceptable"

Comment: @Clare On what grounds?

Comment: If Lewis had written "...to hope earnestly..." no one would have noticed and he would still have avoided the split infinitive. The same thing applies to the old Star Trek introduction "...to go boldly in search of strange new worlds" would've carried the same meaning and not upset the pedants, however some of the power might have been lost.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Lewis was trying to avoid a [split infinitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_infinitive). If Lewis had used a split infinitive, the sentence would read like this:

> There lurks in most modern minds the notion that to desire our own good and **to earnestly hope** for the enjoyment of it is a bad thing.

But since split infinitives have historically been opposed, he changed the sentence structure to avoid it. The resulting sentence is a little awkward, but I think it's technically correct since all he's really doing is using an adverb to modify a verb.

Comment: Whoa dude...there is a _grammatical_ rule that says the split infinitive is wrong? It's a style choice. (the given sentence chose to implement avoiding the split infinitive poorly)

Comment: I edited to say it was historically opposed.

Comment: @Clare, I agree. I edited my answer to say it was historically opposed.

Comment: What does "have historically been opposed" mean?

Comment: It means that older style manuals opposed the use of the split infinitive but it's now viewed as acceptable.

Comment: It means that Bp. Robert Lowth's 1762 *Short Introduction to English Grammar* was taken as holy writ for a benighted century and a half.  Lowth suggested that since one cannot insert an adverb in the middle of a Latin infinitive, one shouldn't do so in English.  Lowth espoused a number of similar idiot-syncracies...