# It is acceptable to end these sentences with prepositions?

Tags: prepositions

I've heard some talk about ending sentences with prepositions. It seems like the overall consensus is that it is indeed okay.

But, I have come up with a few examples. I am wondering if it is "necessary" or just a choice of style here.

'Whom will you go to the party with'?

or

'With whom will you go to the party?'

Now, because of the sentence construction, you can put with before the whom. But do you need to do this? Is it acceptable to say "Whom will you go to the party with?'

Another example is when you use "which" with prepositions, where you have an option to put the preposition before which. (For which event are you preparing? vs. Which event are you preparing for?)

Is this just a matter of style or choice? Also, is there a more recommended option in formal writing?

As a separate question, is it also a "myth" that you can't use a split infinitive, especially in formal writing?

Comment: Except for using "who" in place of "whom" (which I don't use), I find both your examples acceptable.

Comment: See also https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2117/are-split-infinitives-grammatically-incorrect-or-are-they-valid-constructs